# IE 9 not showing table populated by js

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue with the 'addedItems' table not displaying in IE 9 but if used on Firefox 30 displays as it should. In IE it sends the post data and when I check the HTML with the developer tools it shows the html elements on the page. I have tried to see if setting the table display to block but there was no change.

The purpose of this code is to allow the user to select from a drop down list which type of equipment they want to add, then be able to add any number of items from either the Foo or Bar lists onto the table to be sent in the items[] post variable. The table also has a delete button for every row so that the user may take out erroneously added equipment.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
        <ul>
            <li id="EquipmentSelector" >
                <label for="EquipmentType">Equipment Type</label>
            <div>
                <select id="EquipmentType" name="EquipmentType">

                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                    <option value="0" >Foo</option>
                    <option value="1" >Bar</option>

                </select>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li id = "FooHolder">

            <label class="description" for="Foo">Foo</label>


                <select id="Foo">

                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>

                        <option value="0" >Foo Zero</option>
                        <option value="1" >Foo One</option>
                        <option value="2" >Foo Two</option>
                        <option value="3" >Foo Three</option>

                </select>




            <input type = "button" value = "Add Foo" id = "FooClick" ></input>

        </li>
        <li id = "BarHolder">

            <label class="description" for="Bar">Bar</label>

                <select id="Bar">

                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>

                    <option value="0" >Bar Zero</option>
                    <option value="1" >Bar One</option>
                    <option value="2" >Bar Two</option>
                    <option value="3" >Bar Three</option>

                </select>


            <input type = "button" value = "Add Bar" id = "BarClick" ></input>

        </li>

        <li>
        <table>
                    <tbody  id = "addedItems">
                    </tbody>    
        </table>
        </li>
        <li>

            <input type= "submit" id="saveForm" name="submit" value="Submit"  />

        </li>
    </ul>

    </form>

    <script src = "IEerror.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the IEerror.js file:

```
function prepareEventHandlers(){

    document.getElementById("EquipmentType").onchange = function(){
        var equipType = document.getElementById("EquipmentType").value
        if(equipType === "1"){
            document.getElementById("BarHolder").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("FooHolder").style.display = "none";
        } else if(equipType === "0"){
            document.getElementById("FooHolder").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("BarHolder").style.display = "none";
        } 
    }

    document.getElementById("FooHolder").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("BarHolder").style.display = "none";


    function removeDiv() {
        var parentId = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
        $('#' + parentId).remove();
    }


    var myNum = 0;
    function addItem(getFromId){
        var addTag = document.getElementById("addedItems");
        var addVariable = document.getElementById(getFromId).value;
        var possibleId = getFromId + addVariable;
        if(!document.getElementById(possibleId)){
            var newTr = document.createElement("tr");
            newTr.id = possibleId;
            var myText = $('#'+ getFromId).find(":selected").text();
            var newTd = document.createElement("td");
            newTd.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myText));
            newTr.appendChild(newTd);
            addTag.appendChild(newTr);

            var submissionInput = document.createElement("input");
            submissionInput.name = "item[]";
            submissionInput.type = "hidden";
            submissionInput.value = myText;
            newTd.appendChild(submissionInput);

            var deleteInput = document.createElement("input");
            deleteInput.type = "button";
            deleteInput.value = "Delete";
            deleteInput.id = myNum;
            myNum += myNum;
            deleteInput.onclick = removeDiv;
            var deleteTd = document.createElement("td");
            deleteTd.align = "right";
            document.getElementById(possibleId).appendChild(deleteTd);
            deleteTd.appendChild(deleteInput);

        }
    }

    document.getElementById("BarClick").onclick = function(){
        addItem("Bar");
    };

    document.getElementById("FooClick").onclick = function(){
        addItem("Foo");
    };

};






window.onload = function(){
    prepareEventHandlers();
};
```

EDIT:

Here is a link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTCav/xJVJR/1/

Comment: Provide [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What's `<header>`? IE is bad with invalid HTML. Also you might want to update the jQuery, for example IE11 won't work with jQuery < 1.11.

Comment: You should really consider a client-side templating engine so you're going to get rid of hand-coding this...

Comment: `<header>` is a completely valid tag. its simply an html 5 div that is named header.

Comment: @Banana Instead of `head`???? [`html`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) allows exactly two elements as direct children: `head` and `body`...

Comment: @Teemu `<header>` is a semantic container within the `<body>` element.

Comment: hmm after looking at his code again, i must apologize xD teemu is right, op uses header instead of head which is wrong

Comment: @Banana You're wellcome. Maybe my comment was a bit poorly worded, "What's `header` doing on its current place" might had been better.

Comment: Sorry I meant <head> I typed in the wrong tag when I did the example.

Comment: Looks like your fiddle works in IE9, though I can only emulate it with IE11.

Comment: try to set '.style.display' at table or table-row or table-cell
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: on IE9 in fiddle it does what I want it to do but on the page from my server on IE it won't display the table

Comment: is your server public? if yes, could you provide a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a horrible code, but let's begin:

1. Validate your HTML. i.e. your `<html>` contains the HTML5 `<header>` rather then `<head>`
2. Why do you use native JS and jQuery through eachother? Why not stick to jQuery??
3. Anyway, my nitpicking `<aside>`, to fix your problem change your `<table>` code into:

   ```
   <table>
       <tbody id="addedItems">
       </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

This is because IE9 will make an empty `<tbody>` in an empty `<table>` and use this as table placeholder, you inject the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags straight into the `<table>`

Comment: Another way is to use the [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow) method instead of `appendChild`. I've found it mitigates the need for adding `<tbody>`. It's also got pretty widespread support.

Comment: Sorry OP, I didn't mean to be rude (as I said I was nitpicking). Your code looks great if its your first one.